# How to create an object with n number of children mapped to it

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, relationships

I have a requirement in which I have a parent and which could be related to n number of child, and all the child can have only single parent. What to do if I want to achieve this.

If I do this manually then I will have to create n number of relation fields to it and I do not believe that this is the correct procedure to follow, so is there any other way via which I can achieve this requirement.

Suppose

[image]

Comment: can you more specific what you want to do actually ??

Comment: The question is too broad..how can we decide what child record to be mapped to parent record please provide more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to model this is to create either a **lookup relationship field** or a **master/child relationship field** *in the child object, pointing to the parent object*.

The parent object does not have any reference: **it's the child object that references the parent**.

Whether you make this a lookup relationship or a master/child depends on whether the children could exist without the parent. If they could, then you want a relationship lookup; otherwise you want a master/child. In the latter case, the children will be deleted if you delete the parent.

You said that a child can only have one parent, so you don't want a many-to-many relationship.

For more info, see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm)

Comment: Ok.. I got your point mkorman. It helped me clearing my doubts thanks.